# can not set linux environment variables as I expect

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, environment-variables

I open two terminals. 
In first terminal:

```
export CLASSPATH="abc"
printenv CLASSPATH   ---> output is abc
```

then in second terminal:

```
printenv CLASSPATH   ---> no output
```

why in second terminal I dont have the variable?

Comment: Altering the environment of one process does not and can not alter the environment of a parent or sibling process. This is basic *nix security. Imagine if you could modify the PATH of some other process: you could execute any arbitrary commands.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to work because each program inherits environment, that
is a list of environment variables and their values from their parent
process.  Environment is not automatically propagated to all other
programs on the system but is only inherited by children of the given
program.  To set a global environment that would work in all newly
opened terminals you need set it in the file that is sourced each time
you open the terminal. What file would that be depends on what shell
you use and your system local setup. For example, if you use bash you
should put `export CLASSPATH="abc"` in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: You can now accept this answer to let other users know your problem is solved. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

For accessing global variable you need to put `$` before it. Are you doing that?

try `echo $CLASSPATH`

I think you will find [this](https://codeburst.io/linux-environment-variables-53cea0245dc9) helpful.

Comment: thanks . in that links I found this:Global ENVs are global only in the context of a terminal from which it is defined...

Comment: Wrong, `$` has nothing to do with accessing global variables.